# fadeIn/fadeOut and addClass/removeClass from divs JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css-position, fadein, fadeout

I am using the below JQuery code to add and remove a class that has a display:none property and add a class that has a display:block to three different divs positioned relatively. Basically I have a side navigation that has three links that, when clicked, I want to displays different divs on the page, one fading out and then the other fading in.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#what-we-do, #location').hide();
    $('#who-we-are').show();
});

$(function () {
    $("#show-main-who").mousedown(function () {
        $('#what-we-do, #location').fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $(this).addClass('hide-info');
            $(this).removeClass('show-info');
        });
    });
    $('#show-main-who').mouseup(function () {
        $('#who-we-are').fadeIn('fast', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hide-info');
            $(this).addClass('show-info');
        });
    });
});
$(function () {
    $("#show-main-what").mousedown(function () {
        $('#who-we-are, #location').fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $(this).addClass('hide-info');
            $(this).removeClass('show-info');
        });
    });
    $('#show-main-what').mouseup(function () {
        $('#what-we-do').fadeIn('fast', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hide-info');
            $(this).addClass('show-info');
        });
    });
});
$(function () {
    $("#show-main-location").mousedown(function () {
        $('#what-we-do, #who-we-are').fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $(this).addClass('hide-info');
            $(this).removeClass('show-info');
        });
    });
    $('#show-main-location').mouseup(function () {
        $('#location').fadeIn('fast', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hide-info');
            $(this).addClass('show-info');
        });
    });
});
```

When you see my website at http://jacobbuller.com/testsites/peacock/ and use the side navigation you can see that the div does fade out but the other div fading in shows below it for an instant, then moves into place. It makes it look choppy and unprofessional, any idea how to fix this without having to make the divs positioned absolutely?

Comment: `$(function(){...}` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){...})` and you should probably merge all your code inside a single ready handler. Also why not bind to the the click event instead of mousedown/mouseup and give a class to your navigation links so you can just define a single function to handle all navigation instead of one per link?

Comment: And it seems you're using bootstrap so you can just set up some tab navigation and be done with it

Comment: Thanks Koala, I'm actually trying to learn how to use Javascript and JQuery and I would like to do this one through my own coding. I appreciate your comment above, I'll try using the click event and combine the code under one handler.

Comment: If you want to code it yourself, that's respectable, as I said you should also look into having only one function control all the navigation, it's never good when you have multiple functions that basically perform the same thing but for different elements, you can use common classes and visibility selectors to target your elements

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far after making the changes you suggested, but it's still shows the div below the original before sliding into its place once that div fades out...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#what-we-do, #location').hide();
        $('#who-we-are').show();    

        $("#show-main-who").click(function() {
            $('#what-we-do, #location').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $(this).removeClass('show-info');
            $(this).addClass('hide-info');

            });

            $('#who-we-are').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $(this).addClass('show-info');
                $(this).removeClass('hide-info');
            });
        });     

        $("#show-main-what").click(function() {
            $('#who-we-are, #location').fadeOut('fast',function() {
            $(this).addClass('hide-info');
            $(this).removeClass('show-info');
            });


            $('#what-we-do').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $(this).removeClass('hide-info');
                $(this).addClass('show-info');
            });
        });

        $("#show-main-location").click(function() {
            $('#what-we-do, #who-we-are').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $(this).addClass('hide-info');
            $(this).removeClass('show-info');
            });


            $('#location').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $(this).removeClass('hide-info');
                $(this).addClass('show-info');
        });
    });
});
```